# Store image path in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I have a write a code that upload image path into the database but the thing is it uploads the real path (`C:/wamp/www/amref/images/student_profile/childbrah2.jpg`) hence when I fetch the path form the database in order to display the image it gives me the error that the link is broken. I want to store only (images/student_profile/childbrah2.jpg).

**The controller code:**

```
$config['upload_path'] = '../images/student_profile/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = "2048000"; // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
        $config['max_height'] = "768";
        $config['max_width'] ="1024";

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){

             echo '<h4 style="color: red;">

                    Failure! </h4>

                    <p style="color: red;">'.$this->upload->display_errors().'</p>';



        } else {
            $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();

            $image = base_url($data_upload_files['full_path']);
```

Comment: try with base64 upload mathod

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Because you inserting `$config['upload_path'] = '../images/student_profile/'`, so path is `C:/wamp/www/amref/images/student_profile/`.

If you enter this as `C:/wamp/www/amref/images/student_profile/` this will not work in your server. Because in your server there is no partition call `C:`.

So use your path as it is.

### Edit

```
<?php

    $old = 'C:/wamp/www/amref';
    $fulpath = $old.'/images/student_profile/';

    echo $fulpath;
```

Comment: But in the EDIT 01 it outputs C:/wamp/www/amref/images/student_profile/

Comment: ya and get image name from database as well

Comment: Why not use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of given hard coded path??

Comment: The Thing is i want to store only /images/student_profile/ in the database

Comment: If i do as in EDITOR 1 the path stored in the database is http://localhost/amref/admin/C:/wamp/www/amref/images/student_profile/childbrah5.jpg

Comment: how do i use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] an example pleae

Comment: `$fulpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`and echo it and see

Comment: The thing is i want to store the path so i can fetch the image with the path i have stored in the databse

Comment: **NOTE** If you use `C:/wamp/www/amref/images/student_profile/` it will not work in SERVER